# threejs geometry triangle rotate not centered

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have been trying for a while, but I can't figure out why my triangle is not rotating around the center. I want 2 triangles next to each other and 1 rotated for 60 degrees. But somehow if I rotate, all corners should be the same size.

Below you can find my code snippet. How is it possible the blue triangle moves to the left? Because the orange right top is bigger than the other 2...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <title>three.js webgl - geometries</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
  <style>
   body {
    color: #eee;
    font-family:Monospace;
    font-size:13px;
    text-align:center;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
   }
   #info {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px; width: 100%;
    padding: 5px;
   }
   a {
    color: #0080ff;
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/103/three.js"></script>


  <script>
  var SCREEN_WIDTH = window.innerWidth;
   var SCREEN_HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;
   var aspect = SCREEN_WIDTH / SCREEN_HEIGHT;
   var camera, scene, renderer, stats;
   var frustumSize = 100000;
   function init() {
    camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera( 0.5 * frustumSize * aspect / - 2, 0.5 * frustumSize * aspect / 2, frustumSize / 2, frustumSize / - 2, -1000, 10000 );
    camera.position.y = 400;
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0xf0f0f0 );
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 50, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000 );
    camera.position.set( 0, 0, 2 );
    camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0)
    scene.add( camera );
    var light = new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffff, 0.8 );
    camera.add( light );
   
    drawSquare()
    
    var margin = 0.2;
    var t = new triangle(0.5);
    t.draw();
    t.createSides(margin);
    
    //
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
    renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

    //
    window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );
   }
   
   class triangle {
   
    constructor(length){
     this.length = length;
    }
    
    draw(color='orange'){
     var h = this.length * (Math.sqrt(3)/2);
     
     var shape = new THREE.Shape();
     shape.moveTo( 0,-h/2 );
     shape.lineTo( -this.length / 2, h / 2 );
     shape.lineTo( this.length / 2, h / 2 );

     var extrudeSettings = {
      steps: 2,
      depth: 0.4,
      bevelEnabled: false
     };

     var geometry = new THREE.ExtrudeBufferGeometry( shape, extrudeSettings );
     geometry.center();
     
     var line2 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: color} ) );
     line2.position.set(0, 0, 0);
     scene.add(line2);
     this.mesh = line2;
    }
    
    createSides(margin){
     for(var i = 0;i<3;i++){
      var t = new triangle(this.length);
      t.draw('blue');
      //t.mesh.position.x += this.length;
      t.mesh.geometry.rotateZ(THREE.Math.degToRad(60));
     }
    }
   }
   
   function drawSquare(){
    var size = 1;
    var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
    geometry.vertices.push(
     new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0),
     new THREE.Vector3(size, 0, 0),
     new THREE.Vector3(size, size, 0),
     new THREE.Vector3(0, size, 0),
     new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));
    var line2 = new THREE.Line(geometry, new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({color: "red"}));
    line2.position.set(-size/2, -size/2, 0);
    scene.add(line2);
   }
   function onWindowResize() {
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
   }
   //
   function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    render();
   }
   function render() {
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
   }
   
   init();
   animate();
  </script>

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there any reason you aren't using the [built in triangle](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/math/Triangle)? It looks like your triangle is rotating around the center of the scene.

Comment: The orange triangle is positioned 0, 0, 0 which is the center. So the blue isn't really rotating around the center. To test this, I already tried a new sphere at 0,0,0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The center or the center of the [Circumscribed circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumscribed_circle) of an [Equilateral triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equilateral_triangle) is not the center of the bounding box:

A Equilateral triangle where (0, 0) is the the center of the circumscribed circle is:

```js
var l = this.length;
var h = l * Math.sqrt(3) / 2; // 0.866
shape.moveTo(  0,      h * 2/3 );
shape.lineTo( -l / 2, -h * 1/3 );
shape.lineTo(  l / 2, -h * 1/3 );
```

Furtner note that, the function [`.center()`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/BufferGeometry.center) of [`THREE.BufferGeometry`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/BufferGeometry)

> Center the geometry based on the bounding box.

you have to remove it:

`var geometry = new THREE.ExtrudeBufferGeometry( shape, extrudeSettings );`
<s>`geometry.center();`</s>

Of course the triangle is not centered to the box, but it roates around the center of the circumscribed circle. But this can be compensated by shifting the triangle along the y axis by `-h/6`:

```js
var line2 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: color} ) );
line2.position.set(0, -h / 6, 0);
```

See the example.

```js
var SCREEN_WIDTH = window.innerWidth;
var SCREEN_HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;
var aspect = SCREEN_WIDTH / SCREEN_HEIGHT;
var camera, scene, renderer, stats;
var frustumSize = 100000;
var triangles = [];
var rot = 0
function init() {
    camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera( 0.5 * frustumSize * aspect / - 2, 0.5 * frustumSize * aspect / 2, frustumSize / 2, frustumSize / - 2, -1000, 10000 );
    camera.position.y = 400;
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0xf0f0f0 );
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 50, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000 );
    camera.position.set( 0, 0, 2 );
    camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0)
    scene.add( camera );
    var light = new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffff, 0.8 );
    camera.add( light );

    drawSquare();
    drawCircle(1.0);
    var margin = 0.2;
    var t = new triangle(1.0);
    t.draw();
    t.createSides(margin);
    
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
    renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

    window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );
}

class triangle {

    constructor(length){
        this.length = length;
    }
    
    draw(color='orange'){
      
        var shape = new THREE.Shape();

        var l = this.length;
        var h = l * Math.sqrt(3) / 2; // 0.866
        shape.moveTo(  0,      h * 2/3 );
        shape.lineTo( -l / 2, -h * 1/3 );
        shape.lineTo(  l / 2, -h * 1/3 );

        var extrudeSettings = { steps: 2, depth: 0.0, bevelEnabled: false };
        var geometry = new THREE.ExtrudeBufferGeometry( shape, extrudeSettings );
        //geometry.center();
        
        var triangle = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {
              color: color,
              polygonOffset: true,
              polygonOffsetFactor: 1.0,
              polygonOffsetUnits: 4.0 } ) );
              triangle.position.set(0, -h / 6, 0);
        scene.add(triangle);
        this.mesh = triangle;
    }
  
    createSides(margin){
        for(var i = 0;i<1;i++){
            var t = new triangle(this.length);
            t.draw('blue');
            //t.mesh.position.x += this.length;
            t.mesh.geometry.rotateZ(THREE.Math.degToRad(60));
            triangles.push(t);
        }
    }
}

function drawSquare(){
    var size = 1;
    var geometry1 = new THREE.Geometry();
    geometry1.vertices.push(
        new THREE.Vector3(-size/2, -size/2, 0), new THREE.Vector3(size/2, -size/2, 0),
        new THREE.Vector3(size/2, size/2, 0), new THREE.Vector3(-size/2, size/2, 0));
    var line1 = new THREE.LineLoop(geometry1, new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({color: "green"}));
    line1.position.set(0, 0, 0.0);
    scene.add(line1);
    var geometry2 = new THREE.Geometry();
    geometry2.vertices.push(
        new THREE.Vector3(-size/2, -size/2, 0), new THREE.Vector3(size/2, size/2, 0),
        new THREE.Vector3(size/2, -size/2, 0), new THREE.Vector3(-size/2, size/2, 0));
    var line2 = new THREE.LineSegments(geometry2, new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({color: "green"}));
    line2.position.set(0, 0, 0.0);
    scene.add(line2);
}

function drawCircle(l){
    var h = l * 0.866;
    var geometry3 = new THREE.Geometry();
    geometry3.vertices.push(
        new THREE.Vector3(0, 0), new THREE.Vector3(0, h * 2/3),
        new THREE.Vector3(0, 0), new THREE.Vector3(-l / 2, -h * 1/3), 
        new THREE.Vector3(0, 0), new THREE.Vector3(l / 2, -h * 1/3));
    var line3 = new THREE.LineSegments(geometry3, new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({color: "red"}));
    line3.position.set(0, -h/6, 0.0);
    scene.add(line3);
    var geometry4 = new THREE.CircleGeometry( h * 2/3, 128 );
    geometry4.vertices.shift();
    var line4 = new THREE.LineLoop( geometry4, new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: "red" } ) );
    line4.position.set(0, -h/6, 0.0);
    scene.add(line4);
}

function onWindowResize() {
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
}

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    render();
}

function render() {
    triangles[0].mesh.geometry.rotateZ(THREE.Math.degToRad(1));
    rot += 1;
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}

init();
animate();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/102/three.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: So my triangle was not really a triangle? By that I mean it was not correctly centered?

Comment: @Niels It was a perfect equilateral triangle, but it was "centered" to its bounding box. Note pivot has to be that point which has the same distance to each corner. This is point is not the center of the bounding box.